# Comparing two nodes in XPath

Tags: xpath, abstract-syntax-tree, pmd

I am writing an Xpath Query to be used as a rule in PMD. 
Now

```
//Method/ModifierNode[Annotation[@Image = 'Future']]/..[@Image = 'randomMethod']]
```

gives me one node and

```
//ForEachStatement
    //MethodCallExpression
        [@MethodName = 'randomMethod']
```

gives me another.

I want to compare these two and see whether the name of the node in the first query and the name of the node in the second query are same or not.

I am doing this

```
//ForEachStatement
    //MethodCallExpression
        [@MethodName = //Method/ModifierNode[Annotation[@Image = 'Future']]/..[@Image]]
```

This is not working at all and is returning zero matched nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an issue with the types of values you are comparing

`@MethodName` is a string.

`//Method/ModifierNode[Annotation[@Image = 'Future']]/..[@Image]` selects a node (making sure it has a non-empty image).

So when comparing both, it will always be false. You want to get the name of the method node in the second selector, so you can compare strings. You can do so by doing…

`//Method/ModifierNode[Annotation[@Image = 'Future']]/../@Image`

So your XPath should look like

```
//ForEachStatement
    //MethodCallExpression
        [@MethodName = //Method/ModifierNode[Annotation[@Image = 'Future']]/../@Image]
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. So correct me if I am wrong, in Xpath [@Image] will result in a node (as you are using an attribute) and `/@Image` will actually result in the value of Image attribute.

Comment: correct! `[]` is a filter on a node, not a selector. `/@Image` actually selects the image rather than filtering nodes by the contents of the image.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wish I could upvote your answer but sadly doesn't have repo points to do that